# Como exibir o nome de uma pessoa dentro da tag de legenda title="" que está em um <input> em formulário PHP?

Tags: php, html

Estou fazendo um sistema acessível para uma pessoa com deficiência visual e o meu maior desafio é deixar as coisas acessíveis, na minha página de `Atualizar cliente` a pessoa escolhe o cliente no `ID cliente` que retorna um `<select>` com todos os clientes cadastrados, o que eu gostaria de saber é o seguinte:

- Como faço para exibir o nome de uma pessoa escolhida no `ID cliente` para ser exibida nos inputs abaixo pela tag de legenda conhecida como `title=""`?

Exemplo :

- `ID Cliente` possui dois clientes: Leandro e Maria
- `Nome` tem uma tag de legenda chamada `title=""` que está escrita como `title="Campo para atualizar o nome de"`.
- **Esse aqui: `<p> Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" title="Campo para atualizar o nome de"  size=30 maxlength="30" required=""> </p>`**
- Toda vez que eu escolhesse Leandro no `ID cliente` a tag `title=""` no input `Nome` mostraria `title="Campo para atualizar o nome de Leandro"` quando eu passasse o mouse nesse input.
- Toda vez que eu escolhesse Maria no `ID cliente` a tag `title=""` no input `Nome` mostraria `title="Campo para atualizar o nome de Maria"` quando eu passasse o mouse nesse input.

### A imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### O código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Atualizar cliente </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/WEB/css/css.css"> 
    <script>
        function exibirNome() {
            var nome = document.querySelector("#nome").value;
            if (nome) {
                alert(nome + " foi atualizado(a) com sucesso!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        require_once '../conexao/conexao.php'; 
        if(isset($_POST['Atualizar'])){  
            $cd_cliente = $_POST['cd_cliente'];
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            try {
                $atualizacao = "UPDATE cliente SET nome = :nome WHERE cd_cliente = :cd_cliente";
                $atualiza_dados = $conexao->prepare($atualizacao);
                $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':cd_cliente',$cd_cliente);
                $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':nome',$nome);
                $atualiza_dados->execute(); 
            } catch (PDOException $falha_atualizacao) {
                echo "A atualização não foi feita".$falha_atualizacao->getMessage();
            }
        }
        // Query que seleciona chave e nome do cliente
        $seleciona_nomes = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_cliente, nome FROM cliente");
        // Resulta em uma matriz
        $resultado_selecao = $seleciona_nomes->fetchAll();  
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <p> ID cliente:
        <select name="cd_cliente" required="" title="Caixa de seleção para escolher o cliente a ser atualizado">
            <option value="" title="Opção vazia, escolha abaixo o cliente a ser atualizado"> </option>
            <?php
                foreach ($resultado_selecao as $valor) {
                    echo "<option value='{$valor['cd_cliente']}'>{$valor['nome']}</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p> Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" title="Campo para atualizar o nome de"  size=30 maxlength="30" required=""> </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" name="Atualizar" onclick="exibirNome()" title="Botão para confirmar a atualização do cliente" value="Atualizar cliente"> </p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode deixar o input inicialmente sem o atributo `title`, e usar o evento `change` para concatenar o texto padrão do title + o nome da pessoa selecionada no select:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ // aguarda o carregamento do DOM
   
   const cd_cliente = document.querySelector('[name="cd_cliente"]'); // seleciona o select
   const title = 'Campo para atualizar o nome de '; // string padrão do title
   
   cd_cliente.addEventListener("change", function(){ // evento change
      let texto = this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent.trim(); // pega o texto do option selecionado
      // se o value do select não for vazio, concatena o nome,
      // caso contrário o title fica vazio
      document.getElementById("nome").title = this.value ? title + texto : '';
   });
   
});
```

```html
<p> ID cliente:
<select name="cd_cliente" required="" title="Caixa de seleção para escolher o cliente a ser atualizado">
   <option value="" title="Opção vazia, escolha abaixo o cliente a ser atualizado"> </option>
   <option value='1'>Leandro</option>
   <option value='2'>Maria</option>
</select>
</p>
<p> Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" size=30 maxlength="30" required=""> </p>
<p> <input type="submit" name="Atualizar" onclick="exibirNome()" title="Botão para confirmar a atualização do cliente" value="Atualizar cliente"> </p>
```

Comment: Tio, Error {
  "message": "ReferenceError: exibirNome is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 1,
  "colno": 1
}

Comment: Opa! Onde é isso?

Comment: É ali no input submit. Acho até melhor você tirar, pois esse submit nem vai influenciar na resposta. Ou tirar a função que está sendo chamada no onclick desse botão.

Comment: no executar, escolho ID cliente clico Atualizar cliente e dá esse erro

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Mas não pro submit funcionar no snippet mesmo não. Tem que funcionar só lá no código do autor da pergunta.

Comment: Certo, então pra que o executar? posta os códigos sem essa opção de executar

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo O Executar é para ver o código funcionando. Quando seleciona um nome no select, o title do input é alterado, que é o cerne da questão.

Comment: aqui só dá erro

Comment: o nome selecionado não vai pro input

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Onde na pergunta diz que o nome deve ir pro input? :D

Comment: Então não entendi a pergunta, muito menos a resposta. O do Gato faz isso

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Eu entendi a pergunta. No título diz "_Como exibir o nome de uma pessoa dentro da tag de legenda title=“” que está em um <input> em formulário PHP? [fechada]_" e no meio diz "_Como faço para exibir o nome de uma pessoa escolhida no ID cliente para ser exibida nos inputs abaixo pela tag de legenda conhecida como title=""?_".. Repare que em ambos ele deixa claro que quer que o nome seja exibido no atributo (ele chamou de "tag") `title`, e não no input em si.

Comment: Você é o cara, ATRIBUTO e não tag. Agora ficou bom

Comment: Leozão, o rapaz da pergunta só pediu pra colocar no title do input mesmo. Coloquei aparecendo no input (também) só pra dar um plus da resposta e pra mostrá-lo como as coisas acontecem. Rs

Comment: @sam é meu mestre !

Comment: ................ ;D

Comment: Interessante o código.

Answer (score 3):

Vê se essa resposta resolve o seu problema:

Adicionamos um evento **onchange** ao seu select(Esse evento acontece quando trocamos a opção (option) do select)

O "**this**" quer dizer que você pegará aquele elemento que sofre o evento (que no caso é o select) e o passará como parâmetro para a função.

Então, pegamos o value do select (o valor que o seu select possui no momento).

Por fim, atribuímos, o valor que está no seu select, como valor do seu input e também concatenamos com a frase que é exibida no seu title.

```js
//Criando função no JS (é chamado quando mudamos a opção do select)
function exibirNome(campo) {

  //Essa variável "campo" é o seu elemento <select>.

  //Verificando se o campo veio com valor vazio
  if (campo.value != "") {
    //Passando o valor (do select) para o title (concatenado com a frase) do <input>
    document.querySelector("#nome").title = "Campo para atualizar o nome de " + campo.value;

    //Passando o valor (do select) para o value do <input>
    document.querySelector("#nome").value = campo.value;
  } else {

    //Se o campo vier vazio, então entramos no else e passamos uma String vazia para o title e para o value do seu <input>
    document.querySelector("#nome").title = "";
    document.querySelector("#nome").value = "";
  }

}
```

```html
<label for="opcao">ID Cliente: </label>
<!-- O "this" quer dizer que quando o evento onchange ocorrer, será passado o próprio elemento que sofre o evento (o <select>) para a função exibirNome() -->
<select id="opcao" onchange="exibirNome(this)">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="Leandro">Leandro</option>
  <option value="Maria">Maria</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label for="nome">Nome: </label>
<input type="text" id="nome">
```

Qualquer dúvida é só falar, brothão.

Comment: Obrigado me ajudou muito esse javascript.

Comment: De nada, brother. Se essa resposta ou alguma outra foi a que mais te ajudou, clique no "V" desta pergunta para aceitar tal resposta como sendo a solução do seu problema

Answer (score 1):

Adicione a seguinte funcao javascript em seu head

```
function onChangeSelect(select) 
{       
   document.getElementById("nome").title =  "Campo para atualizar o nome de " + select.selectedOptions[0].textContent;
}
```

E adicione a chama da funcao no on change do select:

```
<select onchange="onChangeSelect(this)" name="cd_cliente" required="" title="Caixa de seleção para escolher o cliente a ser atualizado">
```

:)

Comment: Obrigado me ajudou muito esse javascript.